# Need to render a list of items/tasks. How can I do it so old items don't get re-rendered?

Tags: reactjs

I am currently pulling from a custom API every second and rendering the items I receieve onto the screen.

Some code of what that looks like:

```
async componentDidMount() {

  await this.grab_slack_user_data()
  await this.grab_items()

  setInterval(() => {
    this.grab_items()
  }, this.state.settings.seconds_per_slack_messages_pull * 1000 )

}
```

```
grab_items() {

  this.setState( { isLoading: true } )

  let url = this.state.settings.api_url + 'channel/' + this.state.selected_channel + '/now'

  return new Promise( resolve => {
    axios.get( url, { headers } )
      .then( res => {
        resolve()
      } )
    })
  }
```

And in my render function, I have this:

```
this.state.items.map(( t, i ) => {
  return <Item task={ t } key={ i } user={ this.state.slack_users[ t.usr ] } settings={ this.state.settings } />
) }
```

I am hitting some issues with some image flickering which would be solved if I didn't re-render items that were already on the screen.

Is there a way to detect already displayed items?

Comment: if your component is same then no matter what your list will be re-render. if you have problem with duplicating of data that can be removed.

Comment: Huh? If the component is same, then the list will be re rendered?? I thought react re renders only if it detects differences. There is no duplicating of data in the backend.

Comment: Hey you can make use of the spread operator. something like `setState({items: ...this.state.items, ...responseArray})` if the newly fetched data is an array.

Comment: @harisu with `this.setState({ items: [...this.state.items, res.data ] })`, It creates duplicates over and over

Comment: Duplicates can only happen if the res.data is having some of the data that is already in the state and if that is the case then you cannot escape from replacing the whole state and everything rerendering. since you will want to remove the duplicate. if res.data is an array you should also spread it with ...res.data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using index as a key. Use a unique id for each item in a list to prevent re-renders

```js
this.state.items.map((t) => (
  <Item task={t} key={t.id} user={this.state.slack_users[t.usr]} settings={this.state.settings} />
))
```

React needs this key to perform reconciliation - determining if an element should be reused or created essentially

Comment: this fixed it!. Didnt know react worked this way. Thanks Tic

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [`react-virtualized`](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized) or the more light-weight version [`react-window`](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-window). It's a component for efficiently rendering large lists. Specifically the lazy loading packages based off them.